# how to Edit Machine type in GCP cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to reduce machine type in Google cloud sql.
I am able to do this by console but I want achieve this by gcloud command.

reference link:https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/edit-instance#gcloud

I have tried below command but not success:

gcloud sql instances patch INSTANCE_NAME 
--backup-start-time 16:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the reference docs for the command here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/patch

You probably want to do something like

```
gcloud sql instances patch <instance> --tier=<machine-tier>
```